# Deltacloud / Ruby LoadError

Tags: ruby, rvm

I've just put a new RVM build with Ruby 1.9.2 on OS 10.6 and I'm trying to get Deltacloud up and running. Seem to have some problem with Gems, but I'm not sure what I'm dealing with.

```
craigb@macbook:>rvm list

rvm rubies

   ree-1.8.7-2011.03 [ i686 ]
=> ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ i386 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p0 [ x86_64 ]

craigb@macbook:>rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.9.2-p290 (found in /Users/craigb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290)
   global

craigb@macbook:>deltacloudd -l
/Users/craigb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require': no such file to load -- server.rb (LoadError)
    from /Users/craigb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/craigb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/deltacloud-core-0.4.1/bin/deltacloudd:115:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/craigb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/deltacloudd:21:in `load'
    from /Users/craigb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/deltacloudd:21:in `<main>'
craigb@macbook:>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

This pull request includes a patch for the problem; the code is updated in git but is apparently not up to date even in the latest available gem.  It's a one-line edit to bin/deltacloudd

https://github.com/apache/deltacloud/pull/3